# Is there any ntpd that can be configurered to listen to selected interfaces only?

Tags: ntpd

My situation is, that I configure many virtual network interfaces for virtual machines and some of my networks do even have two or more addresses. I don't need `ntpd` to listen to all these interfaces, but there seems no option to restrict the interfaces ntpd tries to bind to.
Besides all these *"security"* options in ntpd, for a system administrator, who knows his environment, the best security option is not to listen at all to interfaces. For example it would be more secure not to listen to external interfaces at all, but to restrict access through ntp configuration.

**Is there any ntpd software known that can be configured to listen only to selected interfaces *(as any network daemon should)*?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just the regular `ntpd` provides this. Look at `man ntp_misc` and search for `interface`. You should find:

```
interface [listen | ignore | drop] [all | ipv4 | ipv6 | wildcard | name
      | address[/prefixlen]]
.
.
```

Add the `interface` directive to your `/etc/ntp.conf` with the desired address you want to use.

Comment: It seems that the ntp project needs some documentation updates. Thank you!

Comment: @ikrabbe; my version of NTP, ntp-4.2.6p5-19.el7.centos.x86_64, does come with the `ntp_misc` manual.